# What the different values written on Relay mean?

Tags: relay, solid-state-relay

I want to know what are the different values written on the relay

[image: Relay]

I understand:

- **10A 250VAC** is the max Voltage, Current the relay can handle
- **SRD-05VDC-SL-C** specified the voltage that triggers the relay (is 'triggers' the right term?)

But then what are the remaining values?

- 10A 125VAC
- 10A 30VDC (I think this is the Max DC Voltage, Current the relay can handle)
- 10A 28VDC

Comment: Have you bothered reading the datasheet yet?

Comment: E.g. [SRD-05VDC-SL-C-Datasheet.pdf](http://datasheetcafe.databank.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/SRD-05VDC-SL-C-Datasheet.pdf) found from searching "_SRD-05VDC-SL-C datasheet_". The `28VDC` vs. `30VDC` appear to be down to different rating bodies (`UL/CUL` vs `TUV`).

Comment: Me asking "is 'triggers' the right term" should give you the idea that I dont really understand much about these things, thereby, not understanding the datasheet completely.

Comment: Unfortunately, here isn't really the place for "teach me electronics" questions, but in brief/simplified: `10A 30VDC` and the like specify the maximum current/voltage it's safe to use (DC is much lower because it "arcs" at lower voltages; because AC "reverses" 50/60 times a second, it needs higher voltage to maintain an arc).

Comment: Of possible concern is _why are you asking?_ If for "general education", that's fine; but if you'e planning on doing something _where you need to know what these figures mean_ (as opposed to follow someone else's instructions) then you probably shouldn't be doing that on your own with your admitted low-level of knowledge. (But you probably could ask a question about a specific design and whether this relay was suitable).

Comment: It IS a general education question, and ofcourse I'm planning on doing something with it, with the answers I get here. The low-level of knowledge I admitted- thats what I want to eliminate, which I think I did, by researching and answering my own question. Thank you for the datasheet :)

Answer (score 1):

There are Agency Approval Symbols on the left and right side, above the values.

These symbols represent the approvals for those standards.

Some countries like US, Canada use Mains electricity around 110 volts. The "C" and the "US" markings (on the right) signify that the component is UL recognized in both Canada and the United States.

Thus, values below that symbol are the values for the US and Canada market/use.

- 10A 125VAC
- 10A 28VDC

The values on the right side are for use in countries that use Mains around 220 volts:

- 10A 250VAC
- 10A 30VDC

Different Agency Aproval Symbols can be found here:
http://www.jameco.com/Jameco/marketing/agency-symbols.html